# Android Geofencing with play-services-location 11.0.2

Tags: android, google-play-services, geofencing

I'm trying to implement Geofencing on Android with the GooglePlayServices latest version.

I decided to use Geofencing because I need to know the user's location only when he moves, and I need something very low power consumption because my apps run in background 24/7.

In my code, the geofencing is not triggered if I don't implement the "requestLocationUpdates" of LocationServices. It is really weird because I read that normally we don't need to use this, and it is not low power consumption anymore with that.

Is someone ever implement geofencing with latest GooglePlayService and without implementing "requestLocationUpdates"?

My code :

Manifest:

```
<service
        android:name=".gps.GeofencingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />
    <receiver
        android:name=".gps.GeofenceReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.location.MODE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
            <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Service :

```
public class GeofencingService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

//My singleton
private static GeofencingService mInstant;
public static GeofencingService getInstant(){
    return mInstant;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstant = this;
    mFusedLocationClient = getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    mGeofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this);
    buildGoogleApiClient();
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}


public void addGeofence() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {

        LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(100); // Update location every second

        //use to initiate the geofence region on my position
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location != null) {
            mGeofenceList = new ArrayList();
            mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                    // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
                    // geofence.
                    .setRequestId(idGeofence)
                    .setCircularRegion(
                            location.getLatitude(),
                            location.getLongitude(),
                            Constantes.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
                    )
                    .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .build());
            mGeofencingClient.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(), getGeofencePendingIntent())
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Geofence added");
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            // Failed to add geofences
                            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to add geofences");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });

    //if this line is removed, geofence is not triggered anymore
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }


    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connected");
    addGeofence();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspend");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has failed");
}

public void getCurrentLocation() {
    //mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
    FusedLocationProviderClient locationClient = getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    locationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
            if (location != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, location.getLatitude() + "/" + location.getLongitude());
            } else {

            }
        }
    });

}

 private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
    if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }
//Call a BroadcastReceiver
    mGeofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(this, GeofenceReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return mGeofencePendingIntent;
}

private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Location Changed : " + location.getLatitude() + "/" + location.getLongitude());
}
```

}

Receiver :

```
public class GeofenceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

protected static final String TAG = "GeofenceReceiver";

protected Context applicationContext;

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    applicationContext = context;
    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
        String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(context, geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
        return;
    }

    // Get the transition type.
    int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

    // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
    if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
            geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

        // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger
        // multiple geofences.
        List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

        // Get the transition details as a String.
        String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(geofenceTransition, triggeringGeofences);
        Log.d(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
        Toast.makeText(context, geofenceTransitionDetails, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Send notification and log the transition details.
        sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetails);
        Log.i(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
    } else {
        // Log the error.
        Log.e(TAG, context.getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type,
                geofenceTransition));
    }
}
```

}

Thanks for your help

Comment: have you considered the Awareness api for this kind of task?

Comment: No it's the first time I 've heard about this api! Seems to be powerful! I will get to in to see if I can use it... Thanks Tim!

Answer (score 0):

> You don't have to call **requestLocationUpdates** for adding geoFence.

You only need a geofence with Location(Latitude,Longitude) to monitor.  And no need to use service (**GeofencingService**) for this. Use simple activity and attach `mGeofencePendingIntent` which will receive in **GeofenceReceiver**

It will notify you in GeofenceReceiver when you enter the fence with `Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER`